# Configure Homestead to download composer packages automatically

Tags: node.js, bash, laravel, vagrant, homestead

I want to user homestead vagrant box for my project so every body can just vagrant up and start developing without even need to install node, npm, composer, gulp, etc.
for node modules i run a bash files like this and it's work fine.

```
cd project-name
npm install
```

But i can not do the same with composer since homestead itself it a composer package, it i try to run composer update i get this error

```
cannot load such file -- path-to-directory/vendor/laravel/
homestead/scripts/homestead.rb
```

I don't want to add node_modules or vender folder to repository! I can only annd laravel/homeasted to repository so it is there all the time but still not preferred solution.

my vagrantfile looks like this

```
require 'json'
require 'yaml'

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION ||= "2"
confDir = $confDir ||= File.expand_path("vendor/laravel/homestead",          File.dirname(__FILE__))

homesteadYamlPath = "Homestead.yaml"
homesteadJsonPath = "Homestead.json"
afterScriptPath = "after.sh"
aliasesPath = "aliases"

require File.expand_path(confDir + '/scripts/homestead.rb')

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
config.vm.provision "install requirements", type: "shell", privileged: false, path: "install.sh", args: "/styleguide"

if File.exists? aliasesPath then
    config.vm.provision "file", source: aliasesPath, destination: "~/.bash_aliases"
end

if File.exists? homesteadYamlPath then
    Homestead.configure(config, YAML::load(File.read(homesteadYamlPath)))
elsif File.exists? homesteadJsonPath then
    Homestead.configure(config, JSON.parse(File.read(homesteadJsonPath)))
end

if File.exists? afterScriptPath then
    config.vm.provision "shell", path: afterScriptPath
end
end
```

and my start.ssh file is like this

```
cd project-name
composer update
npm install
```

and here is my Homestead.yaml

```
---
ip: "192.168.30.30"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
hostname: kiosk
name: kiosk
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: "/Users/alirezaahmadi/sib/php/my-project"
      to: "/home/vagrant/my-project"

sites:
    - map: my-project.dev
      to: "/home/vagrant/my-project/public"

databases:
    - homestead

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

My preferred way is to only add source code and vagrantfile to repository and when the user gets the project with single vagrant up all the composer packages and node_modules will be downloaded. any idea how can i solve this?

Comment: You should only need to edit `after.sh` and put whatever commands you want in there. You need to provide full paths, such you'll need to use `usr/bin/composer update` or whatever the path is (on mobile, can't think of it off the top of my headd)